# How to delete file that has invalid name?

Tags: windows, ntfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Files with illegal filenames](https://superuser.com/questions/90227/files-with-illegal-filenames)

I've accidentally created *-?.tgz* file on my NTFS hdd (working under linux). And I'm just curious is it possible to delete it under Windows 7 using standard tools?

Things I've tried:

1) **move *.tgz die.tgz** gave me same error *"The file name you specified is not valid or too long"*

2) File had no short windows name, so I was not able to delete it using short name

Comment: Actually looks like a dupe - I've flagged as such and removed my answer

Answer (score 2):

It's only a suggestion because I can't try now.
In the past I have gotten rid of files with invalid names
(mainly files with a terminating space) with this command:

```
del "\\?\c:\full_path_to_file\-?.tgz"
```

Comment: This is the 2nd time in a few days I've seen posts with path syntax like `\\?\` and `\-?`. It is new to me. Can you give an explanation and/or reference?

Comment: @dbenham: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: @dbenham The weird filename has been created with Linux on a Windows Partition. I have used that syntax to remove files with an added space at the end of the name. In the Alex link you will find all the details

Comment: C:\Users\Anton>del "\\?\D:\temp\-?.tgz"
\\?\D:\temp\-?.tgz
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

doesn't work

Comment: @Alex @Steve - Thanks, the link is exactly what I was looking for. I see how it enables working with names that end with space or dot. But it does not help with reserved characters like `?*<>/\|:"`, (not from the command line, anyway).

Comment: @dbenham there is this [utility - DelInvFile](http://www.purgeie.com/delinv/index.htm), but now is no more free

Comment: I also wonder if any disk check/repair utilities can detect and fix the problem. The cheapest solution might be to boot again into Linux and delete the file from there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting double quotes around the file name?

You can also try typing "del " then keep pressing Tab when you are in the same directory as the file - this will loop through the files in that folder.

Comment: It's worth a try.