# How to remove a directory called C: under Windows?

Tags: windows

I read this question:

[How to delete (invalid) files with colon in their name under Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/165395/how-to-delete-invalid-files-with-colon-in-their-name-under-windows)

This doesn't seem to work for a directory named `C:` though.

I have a directory named `F:\VM\C:` any chance to remove it using Windows?

I tried `rmdir "\\?\F:\VM\C:"` which didn't work.

Comment: There are multiple duplicates on this subject.  You can try: http://superuser.com/questions/90227/files-with-illegal-filenames or: http://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-xp-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character or: http://superuser.com/questions/165395/how-to-delete-invalid-files-with-colon-in-their-name-under-windows and just try some of the alternate answers.

Comment: @Ramhound Ok, all cmd based solutions in these answers have failed so far. Maybe I'll have some luck with specialized tools. Since the file was created on Linux it should be no problem to delete it using Linux, but that's not my question here :)

Comment: I also had a similar problem which had several different solutions, one of which may help: http://superuser.com/questions/229563/how-to-delete-files-and-folders-that-cannot-be-deleted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are definitely not concerned with the contents of the folder in question, running a chkdsk on the volume may end up being a quick fix for you, especially if there are indeed behind-the-scenes problems that may need fixing too:

**`chkdsk f: /f /v`** (the /v so you can see what's going on + you could always run it without the /f in read-only mode first to see if it actually finds anything wrong to fix)

*Note - there is always the chance that running a chkdsk can screw your data up so always ensure that you have a backup.*

Comment: That worked and restored the "file contents" to "F:\found.000\file0000.chk", etc.