# Can't delete folder due to incorrect syntax / name

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

Somehow I have a folder called "http:" on my computer, I can't delete or access or rename it. When I try to delete I get the message "The file name you specified is not valid or too long, specify a different file name".

I can't seem to do anything with that directory.

I have win 7 64 bit, I'm just trying to delete it normally.

Also, I checked properties > security, and it says the info is either unavailable or can't be displayed.

Comment: What Operating system? How are you attempting to delete it?

Comment: Did you try `rd http*`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete (invalid) files with colon in their name under windows](http://superuser.com/questions/165395/how-to-delete-invalid-files-with-colon-in-their-name-under-windows), [How to remove a directory called C: under Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/543919/how-to-remove-a-directory-called-c-under-windows?lq=1)