# Can't delete “sage = {” file

Tags: windows-7

I had this file appear seemingly randomly in my Ruby on rails project folder. The file is "sage = {". I'm not sure where it came from.

When i try to delete it, Windows 7 says that it cannot find this file and it doesn't exist. And if I try to delete the folder, it says that the folder is not empty.

The file is 0 bytes in size. It is an empty file with no information in it.

-- The only workaround I have found, is to make a new folder, and copy all other files out of the original folder, into the new folder. But this leaves me with a bunch of un-deletable folders which just contain this mystery Sage file.

Where did this come from? How can i get rid of it?

Comment: Do any of the tools on [Files with Illegal Filenames](http://superuser.com/questions/90227/files-with-illegal-filenames) help?