# How would I go about creating a filename with invalid characters such as :?> ?

Tags: filenames

I need to do create a file with a filename such as `:>?`, is this possible somehow? Windows stops it.

Comment: Well each restricted character has another meaning or usage, so if a file or folder name did contain them it could cause Bad Things™ to happen. Mind if I ask why you are trying to do this?

Comment: @DMA57361, when I did this a few years ago, I was testing some things. If I recall correctly, the results were amusing but I don’t recally anything specifically *bad* happening. At most, I was simply unable to access them. (Though I suppose it could cause trouble if for example, you happened to have files named `a`, `b`, and `a>b` and tried to view the last file as using `type a>b`. Oops.)

Comment: @moorecast, when I did this a few years ago, I made the files/directories with dummy names, then used a disk-editor to manually set the names in the directory entries directly. Of course that was on a FAT32 volume, so it was very easy. It would be a little harder on an NTFS volume.

Comment: `Mind if I ask why you are trying to do this?` Maybe to implement a (poor) [copy-protection](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yIv0z.png)?

Comment: "I need to do create a file with a filename such as :>?" -- I doubt that you need to do that.

Comment: I have used `sed(1)` to edit partition tables before; I wonder how hard it'd be to go in and edit inode data to artificially change file names…

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the reserved characters when creating folders or files due to them being part of system functions.

What I recommend you do is look through the `Character Map` application - You can go to run and type `charmap`.

from here, you may be able to find alternate symbols that look the same, for example:

(copy and paste these, you will see that they are different)

Instead of forward slash `/` - you can use a division symbol `∕`

Instead of Colon `:` - you can use the modifier letter colon `꞉`

and so on!

[image]

Comment: Making it even harder to delete! :-)

Comment: @Arjan - only via command prompt.. even then you can use the tab key for autocomplete.

Comment: `/` is a slash - not a backslash

Comment: I used to use this trick for certain situations like when I need to put a question in a filename (*why oh why did Microsoft make the question mark reserved‽* ఠ_ఠ) Unfortunately, I had to stop using *any* non-ASCII characters because they cause problems with things like defrag programs which for some reason seem to be unable to move files that have Unicode characters in their names. ಠ~ಠ

Comment: Come to think of it, this answer doesn’t actually answer the question either. There are answers below that *do*, so this too should just be a comment.

Comment: @Synetech the question mark is reserved because it is a wildcard character (not only for windows, but *nix systems as well)

Comment: @PCLuddite, yes, I know; my point is that it is a common punctuation mark, so making it unusable for filenames is a massive PITA.

Comment: Hello @WilliamHilsum I tried to copy the asterics character from the charmap, map I cannot paste it in the name of a file. How could I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 7):

You can boot from a Linux disk (such as [Knoppix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knoppix)), and mount the NTFS partition.

Linux has much less restrictions on files names, and will let you create such names (I have tried it).

Comment: With the caveat that you'll have a *very* bad time trying to do anything with that file once you're back in Windows.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Yes, but that may actually be the point - maybe OP wants to have some type of copy-protection, or just a prank.

Answer (score 5):

***Some operating systems prohibit some particular characters from appearing in file names:*** (Resource from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename))

**/**   **slash**   used as a path name component separator in Unix-like, Windows, and Amiga systems. (The MS-DOS command.com shell would consume it as a switch character, but Windows itself always accepts it as a separator[2][vague])

**\**    **backslash**   Also used as a path name component separator in MS-DOS, OS/2 and Windows (there is no difference between slash and backslash); allowed in Unix filename

**?**   **question mark**   used as a wildcard in Unix, Windows and AmigaOS; marks a single character. Allowed in Unix filenames

***     asterisk**  used as a wildcard in Unix, MS-DOS, RT-11, VMS and Windows. Marks any sequence of characters (Unix, Windows, later versions of MS-DOS) or any sequence of characters in either the basename or extension (thus "*.*" in early versions of MS-DOS means "all files". Allowed in Unix filenames,

**:     colon**     used to determine the mount point / drive on Windows; used to determine the virtual device or physical device such as a drive on AmigaOS, RT-11 and VMS; used as a pathname separator in classic Mac OS. Doubled after a name on VMS, indicates the DECnet nodename (equivalent to a NetBIOS (Windows networking) hostname preceded by "\".)

**|     vertical bar**  designates software pipelining in Unix and Windows; allowed in Unix filenames

**"     quotation mark**    used to mark beginning and end of filenames containing spaces in Windows

**<     less than**     used to redirect input, allowed in Unix filenames

**>     greater than**  used to redirect output, allowed in Unix filenames

**.     period**    allowed but the last occurrence will be interpreted to be the extension separator in VMS, MS-DOS and Windows. In other OSes, usually considered as part of the filename, and more than one full stop may be allowed.

Comment: You can safely dial down the <bold> hyperbole: it is possible to import files with illegal characters, http://superuser.com/questions/31587.

Comment: The question isn’t ***why** can’t I use some characters in filenames*; it is ***how** can I force the use of reserved characters*. As such, this answer is an answer to a *different* question. At most, this should be a comment with a link to the Wikipedia article.

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to manually edit the hard drive using a program like [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/). If you do this though, most likely the files won't be accessible by any program. For example, if you tried to open a file named `abc\def.txt`, you'd get a message that the directory `abc` doesn't exist.

Comment: +1 This is how I did a while back. I was *easily* able to use every single reserved character by directly editing the FAT directory entries. (It’s also possible in NTFS, but slightly more involved.)

Answer (score 3):

You can install the Subsystem for Unix Applications if you're on Ultimate or Enterprise. From there you can create such names.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in git bash.

```
mkdir "*"
```

asterisks show as • though :/

Comment: That's not a reserved character on Linux.

Comment: Probably should have specified, the windows application git bash. Besides, in the question, 'windows' is specified.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does. If you try to create a filename with an illegal character in git bash, you'll actually get a Unicode private use character in place of it (U+F02A in place of `*`), that then gets translated back when you try to access it from there. But as far as native Windows programs are concerned, it really is the private use character in the name.