# Get a colon in a Windows filename

Tags: windows, command-line, rename, filenames

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How would I go about creating a filename with invalid characters such as :?>?](https://superuser.com/questions/187469/how-would-i-go-about-creating-a-filename-with-invalid-characters-such-as)

Yes I know it is not allowed, but I want to do it anyways. Any workarounds?

Comment: A colon is only allowed in Windows 7 [GI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrointestinal) edition.

Comment: Note that if you succeed, you won't be able to access the file from any normal Windows application.

Comment: Use one of these: ﹕：︓꞉

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot.

This isn't a case of escaping the character to get around a GUI or command line limitation, this is a restriction in the kernel.  The colon is used for identifying the file stream you are accessing.

Your options are to strip the colons on the source, or replace them with a unicode character that looks like a colon but isn't.

Comment: Apparently Linux has no trouble saving files with `:` in the name to an NTFS file system. Not sure if WSL2 has safeties to prevent this, but you can always boot Linux separately (for example from a live USB). However, Windows will not be able to access or even rename such files.