# Deleting a folder named <error> in Windows XP

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, netbeans

For my job, I switch between Windows XP and Ubuntu, using Netbeans as IDE.

Now, I don't know why, but Netbeans on Ubuntu some times creates a folder named `<error>`, and places it into the build subfolder on my project.

When I try to launch it from Windows XP, Netbeans tells me that it can't build the project because it can't delete this folder.

I can't delete it also from Windows XP or use these commands in the prompt: `deltree` and `rm`

How can I remove these folders without having to reboot into Ubuntu?

Comment: Does the '<error>' folder have any strange permissions?

Comment: The angle bracket characters are not legal to use in a folder name in Windows.  They are both redirection operators.  Getting rid of the folder should be possible, but you should also configure Netbeans to NOT use that folder name or you'll keep having this problem.

Comment: You can check the answers to [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-xp-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character)  to rename your invalid-named file and then deleted it.

Comment: @ boot13 : Can you tell me where is this option in netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the file using the command

`del \\?\c:\path\to\dir\^<error^>`