# How can I rename a file whose name is in itself a full path (e.g. begins with "g:\")?

Tags: windows-xp, rename, filenames

Inadvertently, I have created a file named `g:\filename.csv` on Windows XP through a Python script.

Note that `g:\filename.csv` is the filename. Actually it is saved on the F: drive.

I can't rename it using command prompt (`ren oldfilename newfilename`) or using <kbd>F2</kbd> in an Explorer window. It says "can't read from drive" - Windows thinks the file is on the G: drive.

Is there any way to rename it?

Comment: does `*filename.csv` work?

Comment: Also, though you have your solution already, could you post the code that created the file?  I didn't think the Windows File APIs even allowed you to specify an invalid filename..

Comment: outfile = open('G:\\ohlc_file.csv', 'w')   This script was executed from Ubuntu.

Comment: You should file a bug to Linux/Ubuntu. The filesystem driver should know that this is an invalid filename for the targeted drive and consequently shouldn't allow to create such a file. It should still allow to address such files if they already exist, in order to remove or rename them though.

Comment: All right. I will report the bug.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1175933

Comment: There's actually nothing invalid about this file name as far as NTFS is concerned, it's merely a limitation of Windows that prevents it from being properly referenced.

Comment: [Perhaps you can simply run `chkdsk` and it will be deleted.](http://superuser.com/a/240950/98519)

Comment: Next time boot back into Ubuntu and either manually rename it or write a python script to rename it. :)

Comment: what was the code you used to create the file? you made the file while running XP? that looks like a XP bug. I remmeber I had made something similar long back. used java to rename it - cd to that folder in prompt, called program with * and then renamed it (folder had only 1 file)

Comment: [this guy has it right](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1175933/comments/4): it’s not a bug, but there is a way to avoid it, which should be used if you want to avoid it; that’s the answer: remove it and mount with the `windows_names` option next time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This couldn't be the fastest solution, but it should work.
If you boot a Live Linux distro you can delete it, since Linux uses a different method to identify partitions and won't be forced to think that your file is a drive.
I suggest you [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/), that has many handy tools for disk and system maintenance and, beside your current concern, is always useful to have it at hand.

Comment: I am dual-booting with Ubuntu. So this can be tried easily. Let me try and give feedback here. Thanks.

Comment: Done. From Ubuntu, I deleted. the file. Thanks.

Comment: I used to have the top rated answer that said use \\?\ before the name. I was wrong and that method will not work, so I deleted my answer. You need to use this answer's method or one of the other answers.

Answer (score 7):

If your OS Windows then you can use the following trick:

```
1. Issue command `dir /X`
2. Find out your file in 8 dot 3 notation
3. Use 8 dot 3 notation for file operations as ren, del, copy, print and others.
```

Note, if you managed to create file with name `con` or some other Windows device reserved names then you are out of luck with the approach.

Answer (score 6):

You could also try...

From a Windows `Command Prompt`:

```
ren "F:???filename.csv" "filename.csv"
```

or

```
ren "F:*.csv" "filename.csv"
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com). The path name filter in it should be more compliant to this type of error, since this doesn't violate POSIX standards. Install bash and fileutils and then try `rm /cygdrive/f/g:\\filename.csv`