# File with illegal character in name

Tags: windows, ubuntu, mac, filenames

I need to access a file on a network drive, but the file has a `:` in its name. This makes Windows rather unhappy. I cannot rename the file through any method on Windows, so I tried a Mac computer. It sees the file and uses a `/` instead of the `:`, but it also throws errors when trying to rename the file. I booted up an Ubuntu live CD to check, but Ubuntu doesn't display the file at all (even with hidden files/folders shown).

I'm at a loss for what to do. I cannot rename, delete, or move the file, so it's stuck there. What can I do to forcefully rename the file? (Deletion is also acceptable, but I'd MUCH prefer saving the data if at all possible.)

This was attempted on Windows 8, OS X 10.8.5, and Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Do you try moving it in OS X and Ubuntu by surrounding the name with single quotes?

Comment: @Peon I do not have SSH access to the remote location, so I cannot run command line stuff from bash. I tried all of the commands in Windows using `pushd`, but the only equivalent (that I know of) is `ssh` in Bash.

Comment: Try opening a command prompt and renaming it using it's 8.3 compliant name.

Comment: @EBGreen I'm not sure how to get it. I used `dir /x`, which is supposed to do it, but that returned the exact same results as `dir`.

Comment: Is the file name less than 8 characters? You can also try using powershell instead of cmd. Do a dir that will return only that file and pipe it to a command to rename it.

Comment: @EBGreen The file name is longer than 8 characters. I hadn't thought of PowerShell; I'll try that when I get back to the computer.

Comment: What kind of errors are you seeing from the Windows GUI and command-line?

Comment: Have you already ran chkdsk? Warning: this may delete the file.

Comment: Did you try using the unicode path? Like suggested here http://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character (Hint: I found this with https://www.google.com/search?q=rename+windows+file+illegal+character)

Comment: Can you show the exact filename as shown by Mac, Windows and Linux? It intrigues me that Mac insists on using a `/` instead of the `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried renaming with wildcard matching? For instance, if the file is *bad:name.bin*, try `ren bad*.bin ok.bin`.

Comment: As a variation to this, try to use the short 8.3 file name: ren bad123~1.bin ok.bin