# Can’t delete filename with odd, long path in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I am using Windows 10 and I downloaded a PDF file with a long name but now when I try to delete the file it doesn't respond.

I am not able to rename, move, delete the file.
I have also tried to delete file using command prompt and failed.

The file path is shown like this

```
\\?\C:\Users\chaks\Desktop
```

Does anyone knows what this file path means???

[this is the properties of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6er2t.png)

Comment: What error do you get when you try deleting it with the command prompt? How long is the file name? Have you tried pressing F2 and renaming the file to a shorter name and deleting it?

Comment: @music2myear thanks for concern

when I use cmd it shows the error file not found

the file name is "ZONE-WISE RECRUITMENT FOR JUNIOR ENGINEER (JE) (CIVIL ENGINEERING _ ELECTRICAL MECHANICAL ENGINEERING), ASSISTANT GRADE-II (AG II) (HINDI), TYPIST (HINDI), ASSISTANT GRADE-III (AG III) (GENERAL _ ACCOUNTS _ TECHNICAL _ DEPOT) AND STENOGRAPHER GRADE-II.pdf"

yes i have tried to rename the file by different ways but it still don't work...

Comment: Please answer the rest of the questions I asked.

Comment: Your file name is too long. You need to shorten it before you can delete it.

Comment: thanks @music2myear I got rid of the file by the help of above duplicate post...

Comment: You may be able to delete it using a wildcard as posted in [File with illegal character in name](https://superuser.com/a/660804/133285). The path is a [UNC path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Uniform_Naming_Convention).

Comment: Often, files like these files are created by dragging images from a Firefox window (e.g. a base64 encoded image preview URL). They can be deleted in a Cmd window using the \\?\ prefix. For example: del \\?\"C:\Users\SomeUser\Downloads\DATAIM~1.URL"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 7-Zip File Manager to delete them.

If you are still having trouble, ensure that you utilize Shift+Delete inside the 7-Zip File Manager. Otherwise, Windows tries to move them to the Recycle Bin (which will fail again).