# Do I really have to mount the external usb hdd on an SMB share to recover my Windows 10 system image?

Tags: windows-10, backup, external-hard-drive, unc, wbadmin

I did a system image backup of my Windows 10 machine using a combination of `wbadmin` and Bareos.

I wanted test restoring it, so I restored the `wbadmin` image files from the BareOS server to an external hdd; which restored to `D:\clonezilla\restore_attempt\F:\WindowsImageBackup` after I changed the folder name of the backup from the [NTFS incompatible](https://superuser.com/a/31606/2293) `F:` foldername.

I then proceeded to boot with my Windows 10 DVD...and then...

1. Clicked `Repair my Computer`
2. Clicked `Troubleshooting`
3. Clicked `Restore System Image`
4. Then in the `Re-image your computer` dialog, the backup from the system state on the local machine appears, but not from the external hdd, I clicked the `Select a system image` radio button.
5. Clicked the `Next >` button.
6. On the next screen `Select the location of the backup for the computer you want to restore`, clicked the `Advanced...` button.
7. In the resulting dialog it requests a UNC path;

Am I required to use an SMB share to re-image my machine?  Or can I just use the external HDD instead?  It seems to me that attaching an external hdd would work faster than sending it across the network, and thus I would rather use that to save time.  Is it possible to do this using a localhost unc path?  I've seen that the external hdd is listed as `D:` when booting into `Restore a System Image` but I am unable to login to the local host.

Comment: Point to the image you want to use.

Comment: @Ramhound I tried using `\\localhost\d$\clonezilla\restore_attempt\` and it asks me for a username and password; since I'm using a DVD to boot the OS I don't know what the hostname/workgroup, username and password would be.  Or do you mean that it should have shown up on the list of images on the `Select the location of the backup for the computer you want to restore`?

Comment: I heartily advice to use [AOMEI Backupper Standard Freeware](http://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) - life will be much simpler.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you, but that's not what my question pertains to.

Comment: It works to restore it over the network...but do I have to do that?   Why should I be required to do that?

Comment: I believe the restore process isn't finding your local image because it's in the wrong location. I'm not at a system I can look for reference but it's something like `X:\WindowsImageBackup`

Comment: @Twisty I actually ended up using a SAMBA share to do it, and I couldn't believe how fast it went!