# Unable to create a directory called '!?'

Tags: linux, mkdir

I am on linux, and want to create a directory called `!?` in a flash drive formatted as FAT32.  No matter what I try, whether it be GUI or `mkdir`, I cannot create a directory called `!?`.  However, I can do it in other places, such as my home directory.  Why can't I do this on a flash drive??

Comment: It's on a flash drive that probably is using FAT32.  I have editted my post to make this more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this table on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) there is "allowable characters in directory entries" column. The entry for FAT32 states:

> […] except `NUL`, `"` `*` `/` `:` `<` `>` **`?`** `\` `|`

The chosen name `!?` contains `?` which is not allowed. Choose another name or another filesystem. Note while `?` is technically possible in NTFS, it may be [problematic in Windows](https://superuser.com/q/31587/432690), so NTFS is not necessarily a good choice if you need this particular directory name.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not using windows, and I can just name the directory "!miscellaneous."

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an escape character before the `!` symbol.

In order to make your directory `!?` you need to write the command as `mkdir \!?` (with no space between the `\` and `!`) or as `mkdir '!?'` (single quotes, not double).

Normally, I believe `!` is used to reference events. I honestly don't know a whole lot about it. I just know how to make your directory by using the escape character, so the shell knows to interpret that character literally.

Comment: `!` is the "command history" character in bash and similar shells – it lets you run a recent command based on its name or first word, or re-use a previous command's parameters. However, it should not affect GUI programs in any way, as they do not make their operations through an interactive shell.

Comment: Both of those only work on my main drive's filesystem, not on the flash drive.