# Rename a file with special characters and symbols?

Tags: command-line, rename, filenames, special-characters

I have read carefully the answers on [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695289/rename-files-folders-with-special-characters). None of them helps me. I have accidentally download a file with non-ASCII characters into my Windows desktop as shown. I cannot move it or rename the file at all.

I have already got installed Cygwin for other purposes. So I assume that I can handle it using cygwin without installing further 3 parties software on my Windows 10?

To navigate to the file's directory:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Users/root/Desktop/
```

The file looks like this on the desktop and on the command line with `ls -b` command.
[image]

In addition, once I said `ls *Twitter*` to list only the mentioned file name, it throws me this error:

```
$ ls *Twitter*
ls: cannot access ''$'\360\235\223\237\360\235\223\270\360\235\224\202\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\275\360\235\223\262\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\260'' on Twitter_ ders '


$ ls
'Yerel Disk (C).lnk'
'Yerel Disk (D).lnk'
''$'\360\235\223\237\360\235\223\270\360\235\224\202\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\275\360\235\223\262\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\260'' on Twitter_ ders '


$ mv *Twitter* newfilename.pdf
mv: cannot stat ''$'\360\235\223\237\360\235\223\270\360\235\224\202\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\275\360\235\223\262\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\260'' on Twitter_ ders '

$ mv ''$'\360\235\223\237\360\235\223\270\360\235\224\202\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\275\360\235\223\262\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\260'' on Twitter_ ders ' newfilename.pdf
mv: cannot stat ''$'\360\235\223\237\360\235\223\270\360\235\224\202\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\275\360\235\223\262\360\235\223\267\360\235\223\260'' on Twitter_ ders '
```

Any help?

**Note**: For the privacy issues, I have just removed some parts of the images.

Comment: There are a lot of methods at https://superuser.com/questions/31587/how-to-force-windows-to-rename-a-file-with-a-special-character?rq=1 from using a Linux liveCD, Cygwin, using a UNC path (`\\?\C:\Users\etc`) and lots of others.

Comment: lol not your fault really, microsoft is such a fail even allowing such file names when file system should simply deny :D